# Como imprimir um PDF existente usando Poppler (Qt5)?

Tags: qt, poppler

Estou usando Poppler para Qt5, mas revirei a documentação da API https://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt5/ para ler documentos PDF existentes, eu necessito colocar a funcionalidade de enviar para impressora, mas não tenho ideia de por onde começar, o máximo que fiz foi isto (ler o PDF):

```
QString filename = "c:/exemplos/meupdf.pdf";
Poppler::Document* document = Poppler::Document::load(filename);
```

E para imprimir o documento PDF existente, a única coisa que consegui imaginar que eu possa fazer é copiar o PDF para uma imagem e imprimir posteriormente:

```
QImage image = pdfPage->renderToImage(xres, yres, x, y, width, height);
```

Mas realmente isso parece bem trabalhoso, eu gostaria de saber, existe alguma maneira de poder fazer isso usando `Poppler::Document` + `QPrinter`, ou algo qualquer coisa que não seja salvar como imagem?

Comment: Consegui achar isso: https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF, não sei se ajuda

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza não isso é diferente, este link que me enviou é para gerar PDF baseado em uma impressão de outra coisa, como um `QImage` ou `QTextDocument`. O meu caso é o contrário disto, eu quero imprimir um PDF existente.